Как обойти проверку на ручной ввод js?
у меня есть форма на сайте, которая просит ввести email второй раз, но только ручным вводом
Как написать на JS текст? Имитировать ручной ввод это уже пробовал

Нужно навести мышку на нужный элемент страницы, и нажать ПКМ.. в открывшемся меню нажимаем "Посмотреть код элемента"... в открывшемся окошке делаем с страничкой все что душе угодно) вообще очень странная защита-безопасность)

Любая имитация события скриптом будет отличаться от "естественного" события, что инициировал человек. Свойство event.isTrusted принимает значение true для событий, порождаемых реальными действиями пользователя, и false для генерируемых кодом. https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events#metod-dispatchevent
